# how to filter particular value from list using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, cordova

I have some values in list and there are alphabets in side of the page.when I click 'A' I need to get the list with label 'A' and value starting  with letter 'A' and also remaining values should display below the values of 'A'.please guide me.Thanks in advance

My code is

```
$(function () {
   $(":input").click(function(){
    var filter=$(this).text();
        if(filter) {
          $(".sidemenu").find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
          $(".sidemenu").find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
        } else {
          $(".sidemenu").find("li").slideDown();
        }
  });
    });
```

}(jQuery));

html:

```
<ul class="sidemenu" ></ul>
```

I need to get the list like android contact using javascript or jquery

Comment: You have to provide more information, e.g. an example of such a list (HTML) and what you have tried so far. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I have edited my post ,please see that.and guide me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use the data filter in a listview. Simply add "data-filter='true'" to the listview definition.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
</ul>
```

This results in showing a searchbar above a listview. You can wright your own filter function or use the default function which filters everything. Just type in a letter or word and it will show all listitems containing that letter or word.